# Proofing a multivariate trigonometric inequality

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, optimization, extremal-combinatorics

Geometrically, I have strong reasons to believe that the following inequality holds:

$\arccos\left(\cos\alpha \cos\beta - \sin\alpha \sin\beta \cos\varphi\right) \leq \sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2 - 2 \alpha \beta\cos\left(\pi-\varphi\right)}$

Analytically, my first approach was to determine the stationary points of the function

$\operatorname{f}\left(\alpha, \beta, \varphi\right) = \arccos\left(\cos\alpha \cos\beta - \sin\alpha \sin\beta \cos\varphi\right) - \sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2 - 2 \alpha \beta\cos\left(\pi-\varphi\right)}$

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to solve $\nabla \operatorname{f} = 0$ for $\alpha, \beta$ and $\varphi$ analytically. Would it be a good idea to look for zero crossings of $\nabla \operatorname{f}$ numerically and afterwards proof their exact solution? How could I then proof that I didn't miss an intermediate extremum?

Are there any ways to simplify the equation further?
Am I taking the correct approach here at all?

Comment: It would be useful to know about the context. I have reasons to believe this inequality arises in spherical trigonometry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry).

Comment: For $(\alpha,\beta,\varphi)=(1,\pi/2,\pi/2)$, the inequality does not hold.

Comment: @mathlove: Thanks for the notice - I posted the wrong version of the inqueality. This is fixed now.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: Yes, the goal is to find an upper bound on the angle at C in a spherical triangle.